# How can I make this MATLAB code fast (m-file script)?

Tags: matlab, math

I want to make the code below fast. It takes so long time to run, and I got this error:

> Warning: FOR loop index is too large. Truncating to 2147483647.

I need to calculate over 3^100 so... is it impossible?

```
function sodiv = divisorSum(n)
    sodiv = 0;
    for i=1:n
        if (mod(n,i) == 0)
            sodiv = sodiv + i;
        end
    end
end

function finalSum1 = formular1(N,n)
    finalSum1 = 0;
    for k = 1:N
       finalSum1 = finalSum1 + (divisorSum(k) * divisorSum(3^n*(N-k)));
    end
end

Nv=100;
nv=[1:20];

for i=1:length(nv)
    tic;
    nfunc1(i)=formular1(Nv,nv(i));
    nt1(i)=toc;
    sprintf('nt1 : %d finished, %f', i,nt1(i))
end
```

The purpose of this code is to check the algorithm's calculation time.

Comment: If it's homework, then `3^100` is taken so big probably so you can't calculate it bruteforce (at least not without specialized software)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will never finish, because it is so inefficient.

For instance, there is a function that counts number of all divisors and is going through all numbers from 1 to N and count. But using an efficient formula would make it run much master.

Let's say that one need to sum divisors of number `a^b` where `a` is prime number.
Instead of calculating a^b and going form `1 to a^b`, one can see that it is better going
`a^1, a^2, a^3, ..., a^n`, because only these numbers are divisors. But you can go even further and observe that the sum of these numbers are [the sum of geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) so the number of divisors become:

sum divisors,  `a^b = (a^(b+1)-1) / (a-1)`

Comment: can you explain what you need to do?

Comment: I want to calculate the sum of divisors when Nv=100 and nv=[1:20]

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm is too general and inefficient for this particular problem.

I understand you want to sum the divisors of 3^100. But these divisors are easily determined.

S = 1 + 3 + 3^2 + 3^3 + ... + 3^100, a geometric series.

3*S = 3 + 3^2 + ... + 3^101

subtract

2*S = 3^101 - 1

S = (3^101 - 1)/2

Comment: do you know how to modify this code? I need to modify this code to calculate the algorithm